# У него было вытянутое(,) почти овальное(,) лицо

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли вторая запятая? Почему?

Comment: Сформулируйте вопрос, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится только перед наречием ***"почти"***. Несмотря на наличие ***уточняющего определения***, запятая ставится только с одной стороны, т.к. отсутствие паузы после слова ***"овальное"*** влияет на пунктуацию, о чем свидетельствует практика письма.

> Вытянутое, [точнее] **почти овальное**

---

*Ни одно из выдвигаемых предположений об одновременной, очень быстрой, **почти мгновенной** смерти 66 здоровых мужчин не отвечает на вопрос. [Притяжение севера // «Наука и жизнь», 2009]*

---

Все это должно было бы сравнительно быстро повести к преобразованию *вытянутых, **почти параболических** кометных орбит в орбиты кругового характера, а затем содействовать приближению комет к Солнцу и их уничтожению. [С. К. Всехсвятский. О происхождении комет // «Наука и жизнь», 1949]

Comment: Здесь не пояснение, а уточнение. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118,4 — пункт 4.

Comment: Нет. Здесь пояснение. Смотрите похожие примеры из НКРЯ.

Comment: Какое ещё пояснение? Здесь сужается значение, а не по-другому называется! Примеры Розенталя: *Их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с флегматичным, **почти** заспанным, лицом* (Тургенев). *Катер шел, все время подвигаясь в черной, **почти** чернильного цвета, тени, отбрасываемой высокими прибрежными скалами* (Симонов).

Comment: Думайте что хотите. Я свой вердикт озвучил. Никакого уточнения тут нет.

Comment: В примерах Розенталя тоже нет? Вы не видите, что ситуация абсолютно такая же.

Comment: Эти примеры никакого отношения к данному не имеют.

Comment: Определение не требует обособления, как, например, обстоятельство. Для него типична пояснительная функция.

Comment: Почти 90% подобных контекстов пишутся без запятой, и не важно, что здесь есть "почти".

Comment: Почему не имеют? *Вытянутое, точнее, почти овальное* (говорим точнее); *флегматичное, точнее, почти заспанное*; *черное, точнее, почти чернильного цвета*.

Comment: Это не практика письма, а исключения из нее.

Comment: Здесь по факту уточнение. См. информацию Розенталя о разнице: https://i.imgur.com/eItCx17.png

Comment: Вы же базируетесь на Розентале, а у него совсем другое. Базируйтесь на Нацкорпусе тогда. И у Розенталя не указано, что это исключение. Но да, бывает не часто.

Comment: Нет. Никакого уточнения здесь нет, иначе бы регулярно в таких случаях ставили запятую. Вытянутое - это и есть почти овальное.

Comment: Пекарев шагнул с берега, утопая подошвой в мягкое илистое дно и в то же время ощутив легкий, почти нежный ожог...; Однако вскоре произошло событие, которое спровоцировало быстрое, почти лавинообразное формирование системы математических школ; Он начинался довольно внушительно огромными черепаховыми очками, но заканчивался несколько разочаровывающе, парой журавлиных ног и хрупкими, почти женскими ступнями.

Comment: Не думаю, потому что слово "вытянутое" — это не то слово, которое надо пояснять. Поясняют слова без конкретного смысла, например "новый", "прежний". И нет, вытянутое может быть непосредственно овальным. Не обязательно почти овальное. Так что нет, не проканало. Также быть черезчур овальным. Вот и уточняется, какое именно.

Comment: Вы не видите элементарных вещей. При уточнении смысл сужают, здесь нет никакого сужения.

Comment: Здесь уточняется, насколько вытянутое! Нет смысла пояснять значение слова "вытянутый"!

Comment: Боже. Нет смысла вам что-то доказывать. Вы не хотите понимать, что не принято такие случаи вносить в уточнение.

Comment: Кожица, которую мы видим здесь и в плоскости, и в разрезе, состоит из плоских, продолговатых, почти табличных клеточек. [К. А. Тимирязев. Жизнь растения (1878)]

Comment: Это вы не хотите понимать. Здесь буквально уточнение по семантике. А то, что люди иногда не ставят вторую запятую из-за интонационной близости, — это другое дело. Уточнение определяется семантикой, а не просто оформлением!

Comment: Вы не видите причинно-следственной связи: не ставят запятую именно потому, что считают это пояснением, а не уточнением. А вы пытаетесь свое уточнение к определениям пропихнуть - бред.

Comment: В данном примере "почти табличных" может не иметь отношения к длине. То же в примере про ступни. А у вас это тоже самое, просто на одну запятую меньше?

Comment: Пояснительные являются вторыми наименованиями по отношению к первым, поясняемым, которые выражают то или иное понятие недостаточно определенно или по каким-то причинам недостаточно понятно. Вы никогда не сможете доказать, что здесь уточнение, потому что при пояснении понятие тоже является недостаточно определенным.

Comment: Если бы это и правда было уточнением, то закономерно бы ставили запятые в подобных примерах, а не отделяли определение от предшествующей части.

Comment: Да, тоже не является достаточно определённым, но тогда не сужается понятие следующим образом: когда уточнение, указывается степень признака: *вытянутое, (насколько?) почти овальное; флегматичное, (насколько?) почти заспанное; черное, (насколько?) почти чернильного цвета*. Вот именно, неопределенный смысл (например, "новый", "прежний" — мы не знаем, о чём говорится), а здесь он определённый.

Comment: Здесь нет сужения: еще раз повторяю. Понятия равнозначны, одно и то же называется по-разному.

Comment: *легкий, почти нежный* — "нежный" может не иметь отношения к лёгкости. Вы притянули за уши примеры. Когда понятия равнозначны, вопрос "насколько?" не подходит.

Comment: Никакого притягивания тут нет. Сила Бунина-изобразителя заключалась в поразительно быстрой, почти мгновенной реакции на все внешние раздражители и в способности тут же найти для них совершенно точное словесное выражение. [В. П. Катаев. Трава забвенья (1964-1967)] Пожалуйста, вопрос "насколько" подойдет, однако запятую не ставят.

Comment: Есть притягивание. Почти во всех ваших примерах второе может не иметь отношения к первому. Не знаю, у меня здесь вопрос "насколько?" не звучит: *в поразительно быстрой, (в насколько поразительно быстрой?) почти мгновенной*. Наверно, из-за наречия.

Comment: Насколько быстрая реакция (почти мгновенная).

Comment: Все звучит, и все поддается разложению на пояснительные компоненты, которые вы не желаете замечать. Паузы также против вас тут играют. При уточнении совершенно другая интонация должна быть.

Comment: Но там не так, а: *Насколько поразительно быстрая? Почти мгновенная.* Такое себе. Возьмите примеры Розенталя с пояснениями, там "насколько?" не подходит. У меня с интонацией всё сходится.

Comment: Вытянутое/почти овальное лицо. Пауза только после слова "вытянутое". Такой вариант: вытянутое, почти овальное/лицо - немыслим для русского языка.

Comment: Зачем брать примеры Розенталя с пояснением, если там совершенно другая структура. У вас есть наречие "почти", которое вносит оттенок уточнения, однако превалирует здесь пояснение, т.к. для прилагательного нетипично быть обособленным.

Comment: *для прилагательного нетипично быть обособленным* — это другое дело. Здесь явно говорится, насколько оно вытянутое. А вы смешиваете всё, и другие подумают, что только в запятой отличие.

Comment: Поясняются неконкретные определения: *новый, особенный, последний, старый, лучший* (из примеров Розенталя).

Comment: Пояснение ещё как-то могло быть без "почти": *У него было вытянутое, то есть овальное лицо.* Но такое высказывание не очень логично, так как никому не нужно пояснять, что значит "вытянутый". Разве что ребёнку.

Comment: Однако я все равно вижу здесь именно пояснение, а не уточнение. Ваше право видеть здесь уточнение (с чем я не согласен)

Comment: Пояснение может возникнуть и в случае, когда первое определение достаточно конкретно (например, выражено числительным), а второе определение поясняет его иными словами. НЕ факт, что это касается только числительных.

Comment: Конкретного смысла (качества) у числительного нет, человек не поймёт, о чём речь, если он не знаком с этой нумерацией. Возьмём пояснение Розенталя: *Розовые, цвета зари, облака показались на востоке* (розовый цвет не обязательно должен быть цвета зари, первое понятие шире второго, поэтому налицо уточнение). Подстраиваем под данный пример: вытянутое не обязательно должно быть почти овальным, оно может быть немного овальным, просто овальным, слишком овальным. Шах и мат.

Comment: Никакого "шаха", а тем более "мата". Пояснение вовсе не должно указывать на абсолютное тождество понятий, достаточно того, чтобы пишущий выделяет нужный ему критерий сравнения и берет его за основу для пояснения.

Comment: Пояснение = переименование. "Розовый", то есть цвета зари.

Comment: Тогда вам надо уже с Розенталем спорить. Всегда было тождество.

Comment: Это вы его вольно трактуете.

Comment: Вы сами говорите, что в его примере с уточнением пояснение. И игнорируете его слова. Всё с вами ясно.

Comment: В данном случае и пояснение можно найти.

Comment: Вы хотите убедить меня, что в приведенном выше примере не может быть пояснения - бред! Вы не видите свою ошибку, считая, что только разобранный пример ученого может диктовать правило.

Comment: Но Розенталь же вам говорит, что уточнение. Было бы пояснение тоже, он бы сказал. А вы их смешиваете и сводите всю разницу к запятой.

Comment: Бесполезно вам что-то доказывать, ой, бесполезно. Мнение Розенталя  - это не Манна Небесная, то, что в каком-то примере он увидел уточнение, говорит только о том, что он увидел уточнение, не более.

Comment: А что тогда манна небесная, что выше? Мнение Ajgy? Дело в том, что вы в ответе ссылаетесь на Розенталя, а у него указано другое. Напишите в ответе, что вы не согласны с Розенталем, что уточнение, по-вашему, от пояснения не отличается. Уточнение — это когда есть сужение, здесь оно есть. Вы же пояснением считаете все случаи, что смешивает их.

Comment: Уточнение от пояснения отличается, однако в данном случае пояснение, вот и вся разница. На Розенталя я ссылаюсь для того, чтобы автор посмотрел, что такое пояснение.

Comment: Если это уточнение, то на каком основании не ставим запятую? Или, как вы считаете, ее нужно здесь ставить?

Comment: Вы разницу не указали! Естественно, нужно, значение сужается.

Comment: Уже вам 100 раз было объяснено: одно называется по-другому. Вытянутое, то есть почти овальное. Раз нужно, тогда объясняйте, почему в НКРЯ 90% примеров подобных контекстов не содержат запятой? Ваши "я так вижу" не нужно приплетать. Четкий вопрос: структура предложений соответствует.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что понятия не тождественны? Нет, вы не способны это понять. Здесь есть сужение. А когда есть сужение, то уточнение.

Comment: Это вам кажется, что здесь есть какое-то сужение. Его здесь нет!  Я жду ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: За речкой пошли плоские, почти голые холмы. [В. А. Обручев.  Сотни примеров против вас.

Comment: Сотый раз: вытянутое не обязательно должно быть почти овальным, оно может быть немного овальным, просто овальным, слишком овальным. Второе понятие уже, чем первое!!! Плоскость не имеет отношения к "почти голые". И не имеет отношения к прямоугольности. И к Нацкорпусу мы обращаемся, когда в справочниках нет ответа!

Comment: Бред не пишите. Пишущий сам определяет критерий сравнения. Для него плоское и есть голое, для него вытянутое и есть почти овальное, как вы не можете понять этого!? НЕТ НИКАКОГО СУЖЕНИЯ. Декилько дней назад вы мне говорили, что правильно так, как пишет большинство, а теперь в справочниках надо искать, оказывается. Все с вами понятно. Больше не буду отвечать на ваши комментарии.

Comment: Вы гоните? Откуда вы знаете, что у пишущего? При нормальном раскладе они не связаны. Вы считаете, что когда "почти", всегда связаны, но это не так. Так что вот как объясняются большинсво примеров. Голые холмы — это без растений вообще-то! Ага, так справочники можно выкинуть? Нацкорпус уже на первом месте? Нет.

Comment: Но здесь всё просто, ладно, если бы спор был о чём-то сложном. А вы мне доказываете, что 2 + 2 = 5.

Comment: И в примере про "прямоугольный" не было объекта в именительном падеже! Вы даже этого не заметили. (Например: *Оно плоское, прямоугольной формы.*) А потом дошло, и удалили.

Comment: Пример, к которому вы апеллировали, в оригинале написан без запятой. Это Розенталь решил найти в нем мнимое уточнение. Оба офицера скоро показались под его сводами; их сопровождал небольшой плотненький человечек с флегматическим, почти заспанным лицом ― военный доктор. [И. С. Тургенев. Вешние воды (1872)]. Вы абсолютно не понимаете, о чем говорите, зато советовать горазды.

Comment: Это вам к Розенталю, а не ко мне. Здесь возможно уточнение. Но тогда (19 век) правила были другими.

Comment: Шах и мат. Обособленный поясняющий адъективный оборот представляет собой словосочетание с главным словом - прилагательным, которое синтаксически зависит от существительного (согласуется с ним), а по смыслу поясняет, уточняет предшествующее ему прилагательное: Светлые, почти белые волосы прилипли к потному лбу, к ушам, к шее, местами подгорели и порыжели (Залыг.)

Comment: Это полная чушь. Это противоречит Розенталю. Может, вообще отменить уточнение? Вы этого добиваетесь. Это делает уточнение равнозначным пояснению. А тогда нет смысла в двух терминах.

Comment: О чем я и говорю. Вы готовы даже с Грамматикой спорить, пытаясь доказать свою правоту. Не о чем говорить даже больше с вами...

Comment: Остановитесь. Вы хотите сказать, что уточнение и пояснение — это то же самое. Так?

Comment: Просто это противоречит Розенталю. Это делает пояснение равным уточнению. Они не разделяют уточнение и пояснение. У них пояснение уточняет...

Comment: Как видим, они не выделяют пояснение и уточнение. У них разницы нет, и ставят одну запятую. Но позиция Розенталя грамотнее. Но по чём надо ориентироваться, когда имеем дело с пунктуацией? По справочнику по пунктуации или справочнику по грамматике? Ответ очевиден. Ставьте справочник по грамматике выше, раз так хотите...

Comment: Они даже оборот с "или" выделяют только с одной стороны. Вам и это нравится?

Comment: Справочник Лопатина имеет наибольшую силу, так как он новее, в том числе Грамматики. И он не противоречит Розенталю. Там не приравнивают уточнение к пояснению.

Comment: Нет. Не делает. В Грамматике об этом написано в разных параграфах. Где с одной: "Волокнина крови, или фибрин, не отличается резко от белка" (Д. Менделеев). Нет ничего авторитетней Грамматики.

Comment: Что не делает? Чего, где "или", одна запятая? Нет ничего авторитетней Грамматики, когда речь о грамматике. Нет ничего авторитетней справочников по пунктуации, когда речь о пунктуации. Здесь справочники побеждают.

Comment: Не делает пояснение равным уточнению. Нет. Не побеждает. Нисколько.

Comment: Делает ("поясняет, уточняет предшествующее ему прилагательное" — они не разделяют это). У них есть обособление определений перед существительным двумя запятыми? Это вряд ли. Побеждает справочник Лопатина, потому что он новее. А Грамматика уже старовата.

Comment: Очередной бред: что вам выгоднее, то вы и считаете "правильным". При уточнении всегда ставятся две запятые, так что не делает.

Comment: Я за определения! У них одна запятая даже при "или", когда определение. Где такое ещё есть? Не делают, когда определения! Не что выгоднее, а люди изучают пунктуацию по справочникам по пунктуации, а не по справочникам по грамматике!

Comment: Пример конкретный где?

Comment: Там же, последний.

Comment: Где там же? Я не знаю, что вы там смотрите.

Comment: Блин, ну тот же абзац: *Это связано с вопросом о стабильных и переменных, или изменчивых (лабильных) элементах в фольклоре вообще.* Сам пример интересный, так как здесь двойное пояснение.

Comment: Тот, кто ставит запятую, ориентируется на Розенталя, однако есть правило, гласящее о том, что пояснительное определение только отделяется запятой от предшествующей части.

Comment: Ну тут уже не просто пояснительное определение, а пояснительный оборот. Это противоречит Лопатину и Розенталю, но логику авторов Грамматики можно понять. И случай другой, при "или" другое название, а без "или" просто другая характеристика. Ну суть в том, что они всё-таки не рассматривают уточняющие определения и приравнивают их к пояснительным. Потому что у них нет уточняющих определений. У них все поясняющие.

Comment: Тем не менее термин "уточнение" присутствует, просто употребляется тогда, когда речь идет об обстоятельствах и дополнениях.

Comment: Да. Но в контексте определений они их сравняли. Об этом говорит и фраза "поясняет, уточняет предшествующее ему прилагательное". Не было бы такого... Это другой подход.

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что нельзя так сказать: "Вытянутое, то есть почти овальное?".

Comment: Потому что понятия не равнозначны. Ладно бы, если "вытянутое, то есть овальное". Ещё можно было бы с натяжкой согласиться. Типа вытянутый круг — это овал. Но не почти овал (это полнейшая ерунда). "Почти" здесь явно для уточнения. И потому что второе понятие уже, чем первое. Оно говорит, насколько вытянутое.

Comment: По вашей логике, вообще тогда не может быть поясняющих определений, потому что в языке практически нет абсолютных синонимов.

Comment: Во-первых, не синонимы, а другие названия. А во-вторых, это когда есть "или". Без "или" просто даётся другая характеристика, **нет смысловой связи с первой**. У Розенталя: *на одном, северном; очередной, шестой; другим, серьёзным*. Вопрос "какой именно?" прямо просится, потому что у таких определений нет конкретного смысла. Другое дело, когда просто однородные определения, как в Нацкорпусе. Когда "почти", не обязательно уточнение или пояснение.

Comment: Это вы про обычные однородные члены говорите, где нет уточнения?

Comment: Ну да. Про обычные. Такое вполне возможно с "почти".

Comment: Теперь ответ стал честным. Этого и хотелось изначально.

Comment: А если быть ещё честнее, то надо сказать, что в правилах указано другое. Если бы так стали писать чаще, то уже в справочнике Лопатина было бы другое правило, ну или хотя бы было бы примечание об этом по типу того, как делает Грамота. А пока это "просто встречается".